# What's this ceiling mounting system called?

Tags: ceiling

I'm looking to suspend some Wi-Fi Equipment from a roof slab where there's no suspended ceiling grid to clip it to. The suspension is a cable loop that can hang from just about anything (the access points are ~300g) so where there's existing unistrut I can use that, but where there isn't, there's metal plating on the roof slab:

[image: Unistrut suspension.]

I *think* that's just a series of [Unistrut channels](http://www.unistrut.co.uk/index.php?M1=Support%20Systems&M2=Single%20and%20Double%20Channel&#M1) that I can use [channel nuts](http://www.unistrut.co.uk/index.php?M1=Support%20Systems&M2=Channel%20Nuts&#M1) on, but I'm not sure. Can anyone confirm it?

Also, assuming it is, can anyone recommend a part that I can use to suspend a cable loop [such as this](http://docs.aerohive.com/330000/docs/help/english/6.6r3/hm/full/help.htm#hw/acc/PlenSusMount.htm?Highlight=suspend) from?

Comment: Can you please explain "Wi-Fi Equipment"? How many pieces, weight, size, will just 1 piece be located every 20-meters, will equipment need to hang below everything else to reduce interference? I'm thinking a lot simpler than Unistrut stuff with all of those beautiful I-beam ledges.

Comment: @Iggy They're access points. Perhaps 6 of them in various places, about 15x15x3cm and 340g. I already have the suspension mounts for them, however. I just need something to fix a small hoop to that ceiling grid to hang the cable from. (Yes, they'll have ~1m down from that ceiling to get below the level of any obstructions.). I may be able to use I-Beams for a couple of them, but I have perhaps 20cm give in the positioning and there aren't I-Beams close enough for most of them. (That photo isn't really representative of the whole space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the clarification. I wasn't sure if the "equipment" was additional to the access points or if the access points were the equipment. Being just very lightweight access points, the off-the-shelf most everywhere anchoring solutions are quite broad. I'll just present a few options to help you visualize & build upon.

If you'd prefer a single attack & homogeneous look & procedure in only using the ceiling's channels, since they're everywhere. Then, I'd suggest Little L-Brackets Masonry Screwed or Masonry Bolted into the channels with a drilled hole. Due to the small amount of weight we're talking the L-Bracket's one side can be cut or slit to slip in your Loop Cable.

Drilling the holes too big or sloppy can be remedied by bigger Masonry Screws or going to the longer & drill deeper Sleeve Anchor pictured on the far right, these combinations would very closely match the method used for the Unistrut's anchoring.
[image: channel anchor]

The I-Beam anchors can be as simple as a Metal Rod bent around the I-Beam Ledges. Or, a Picture Frame Wire (possible scraps from your Loop Cables) tensioned between 2 of the L-brackets above, you'd just close the "L" down with pliers to a "V". Or, a variation of the below concepts.
[image: ibeamclamps]

The Unistrut's c-bar usage can of course be their nut option. Or, just a simple Plastic or Metal Wire Tie (always trim that tail off) or more Picture Hanging Wire (possible scraps from your Loop Cables) or a Bolt, Nut & Washer assembly.

But, I think those options will get it done in overly securing your Loop Hangers. If this is more than a single in-house installation you might invest in [**a system like this**](https://www.us.hilti.com/direct-fastening/ceiling-hanger-systems/sc-CLS_CEILING_HANGER_SYSTEMS?page=0) for future installations.

Answer (score 0):

Your picture is centered on the sprinkler line. But the cable tray on the right might be used if it only has low voltage cable in it. It appears to have red cable in it that would be fire alarm and low voltage. If it contains power cabling you shouldn't put communications in it unless they are separated by at least 2".

You could hang the boxes for your access points off of any of the threaded rods supporting the cable tray or HVAC with some of [these](https://www.grainger.com/category/rod-coupling-nuts/nuts/fasteners/ecatalog/N-8lo) rod couplings and more threaded rod. If you need an access point in a location without existing threaded rod you will have to drill and anchor some rod of your own.

We routinely make multilevel trapeze hangers with threaded rod and unistrut. Sometimes we add a level later with rod couplings and more unistrut. That is why the cable tray has some extra threaded rod out of the bottom of the strut that they didn't cut off. Future expansion.

Good luck with your project!